# How to wait until element's text had changed in WebdriverJS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriverjs

I've found in [Alister Scott's](http://watirmelon.com/2015/11/04/waiting-in-webdriverjs/) blog how to wait until element had changed to specific value. But I can't solve problem with how to create waiting for element to wait until its text had changed FROM specific value (in my case from '-') to anything else (in my case it's a counter, so I can't set specific value to wait for).

Any ideas?

Comment: Wait until its text isn't equal to the starting value?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. correct.

Comment: Ok, so what's your question? The linked article shows how to use a function in a wait, you just need to negate the result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm totally new in such tests, so I'm not quite understand how to negotiate this `driver.wait(until...)`. Could you please explain it or refer to an article with good explanation?

Comment: Then try harder, because the third example in the article shows almost exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Promises it may get a bit confusing...

```
driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.findElement(By.id('idYouWant')).getText().then(function (text) {
        return text === 'Done';
    });
}, timeout);
```

This bit of code monitors the text of a dynamically changing element with a given ID.

Notice the 2 returns and remember that the timeout is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the existing value before the change, after that you can supply your own expectation function to the `wait` method. Your function should return true when the value is different from the old value.

```
var oldValue = ...;
driver.wait(function(){
    var newValue = ...;
    return newValue != oldValue;
}, timeout);
```